# uWSGI server does not run with & argument

Tags: linux, bash, docker, uwsgi

I build a docker image which runs flask on an uWSGI server. I have a uwsgi.ini file with configuration. When I use

`CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "uwsgi.ini"]`

in the Dockerfile, everything works fine and the server runs, I can access my flask app via the browser. The only problem is that I cannot use the container's bash while it's running, as it is blocked by the uWSGI process. I found that appending an `&` should make the uWSGI run in the background. However, when I use

`CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "uwsgi.ini", "&"]`

I get an error saying

`unable to load configuration from &`

I get that when I try this, the uWSGI thinks I'm passing another argument that it should process. However, I cannot find any way to tell it that it is not the case. Using `docker run` with the `-d` argument also only detaches the container from the current terminal on the host, but when I use `docker attach`, I get a bash that I can't do anything with.

Is there a way to tell uWSGI explicitly that I want it to run in the background? Am I missing something?

Comment: have you tried attaching to your docker image with something like `docker container exec -it <name> sh` where `<name>` is the name of your container?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle No, i didn't know about this possibility. Your solution works. Will you please write your solution as an answer so I can accept it and it's here for anyone who could need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a command on your container by using the `exec` command.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
9fb488c77d55        nginx               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       80/tcp              distracted_brown
```

so here I have an nginx container image running in a container called `distracted_brown`. So I can ask the container to run a command using exec. In this case the command i want to run is the shell `sh`. I also pass the `-it` flag so i can run interactivly with STDIN and STDOUT

`docker container exec -it distracted_brown sh`

this will allow me shell access to the container where nginx is running as PID 1. As a side note you dont normally want to run your CMD process in the background as when PID 1 closes the container will close.